# How do I dynamically assign IDs to form fields with event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, anytime

I am allowing for the user to click a link, which will add a field to the page. The user can click the link to add as many fields to the page as they like. When the field is clicked, a calendar appears, because it is a date field. I am using the Any+Time calendar. The jQuery waits for a click event from the field with a specific id. Here is the code:

```
$('#start_date').click(
        function(e) {
            $('#start_date').AnyTime_noPicker().AnyTime_picker().focus();
        } );
```

The id is *start_date*. The problem is that the user can click the link to add a new field called *start_date* and since the id is the same, the jQuery event listener cannot uniquely identify each field. Is there a known solution for this kind of a scenario?

Comment: @thecodeparadox: Thank you for your answer. It didn't quite work. It worked for the *start\_date* field at first. Then when I clicked to add a new field, it did not show the calendar when I clicked the old *start\_date* field or the new one. The code is: `$('[id^=start_date_]').click(
            function(e) {
                $('[id^=start_date_]').AnyTime_noPicker().AnyTime_picker().focus();
            } );`

Comment: What you can do is append a postfix number to the id like your dynamic control id will be start_date1,start_date2..., may be there is a better known solution for this.

Comment: @MSUH: This is what I am doing. I have an iterator to append to the end of the *start\_date*. So they show as `start_date_0, start_date_1, etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear:  does appending the unique number not work for you?  If you're OK creating the field but it's not attaching the click handlers, then try adding a `class="pickerField"` to the elements when you create them, and change your handler to:

```
$('.pickerField').click(
        function(e) {
            $(this).AnyTime_noPicker().AnyTime_picker().focus();
        } );
```

I believe that should work with jQuery 1.7.2.  If for some reason it doesn't, then try the following instead:

```
$('.pickerField').on('click',
        function(e) {
            $(this).AnyTime_noPicker().AnyTime_picker().focus();
        } );
```

If you're using an older version of jQuery, try using `live` instead of `on`.

Comment: Note that you will still need to assign a unique ID to each field in order for it to work with Any+Time™

Comment: Hi, I actually found the main problem which explained why the additional *start\_date* field wasn't responding to the click event. I was using `elmt.innerHTML += ` which was making the script unresponsive. Your solution unfortunately didn't work. The additional field was unresponsive. Using `[id^=start_date_]` makes the calendar show in the additional field when the initial field is clicked. I have redesigned my form so that I don't need to worry about this problem anymore.